# Benchmarking MyISAM vs InnoDB using Sysbench on MariaDB-10.0.14

Tags: innodb, myisam, mariadb, benchmark

I performed a "read" benchmark on MariaDB-10.0.14 db server using sysbench to compare performance between InnoDB and MyISAM on a single. Below are the sysbench commands i used:

Create test table in subtest database with 1,000,000 records

InnoDB engine:

```
#sysbench --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --mysql-table-engine=innodb --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-user=testdb --mysql-password=testpw --mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock prepare
```

MyISAM engine:

```
#sysbench --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --mysql-table-engine=myisam --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=sbread --mysql-user=testdb --mysql-password=testpw --mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock prepare
```

Perform Read Test:

InnoDB engine:

```
sysbench --num-threads=1 --max-requests=500000 --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --oltp-read-only --mysql-db=sbtest --mysql-user=testdb --mysql-password=testpw run
```

MyISAM engine:

```
sysbench --num-threads=1 --max-requests=500000 --test=/usr/share/doc/sysbench/tests/db/oltp.lua --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --oltp-read-only --mysql-db=sbread --mysql-user=testdb --mysql-password=testpw run


Test Results:

InnoDB engine:
Thread                   Total Time                         Transactions
1                        3823.6033s                         500000 (130.77 per sec.)

MyISAM engine:
Thread                   Total Time                          Transactions
1                        2148.4370s                          500000 (232.73 per sec.)
```

I have two questions:

1. As seen from the results, the total time for MyISAM seems less, which is what i was expecting. But i do not understand why the "transaction per second"  of MyISAM performs worse than that of InnoDB. Can somebody explain that to me why this is?
2. I tried to increase the --num-threads to 2 (to perform multiple concurrency) but with MyISAM, i kept getting an error "failed: 1062 Duplicate entry for primary key". I understand that MyISAM does not support multiple threads, would this be the reason? Insight on this too would be appreciated.

Comment: The TPS score for MyISAM (232 "transactions" per second) is _better_ than that for InnoDB (130).

Comment: Thanks for catching that Mat. Then my main question still remains, why does the test on MyISAM using multiple threads does not seem to work?

Comment: isn't oltp.lua a read & write test ? you should use /tests/db/select.lua for select read only test ?